# Xcode - Couldn’t be opened because URL type http isn’t supported

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, nsdata, nsurl

I've uploaded images to an amazonS3 bucket. I am trying to download a specified user's profile image. Xcode says the file couldn't be opened because URL type http isn't supported.. Am I overlooking something?

```
func retrieveProPic(proPicString: String, userID: String){

    let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
    downloadRequest.bucket = "profilepicturetest1"
    downloadRequest.key = userID
    let proPicURL = NSURL(string: proPicString)
    if let picURL = proPicURL {
        downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = picURL
    }

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Failed to download because of (\(error))")
        }
        if task.result != nil {

            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL)

            {
                self.proPicImage = UIImage(data: data)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            print("made it to have result")

        } else {

            print ("Unexpected empty result")

        }

        return nil

    }

}
```

Comment: Transport Layer Security of iOS 9 for http

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Or if you want to enter them manually:

1. Add `App Transport Security Settings` to your property list as a dictionary.
2. Press the `+` on the newly created dictionary, and select `Allow Arbitrary Loads`.
3. Set the key to `YES`.

---

This should only be used as a temporary solution though, as it's recommended to use secure connections with networking applications.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. Needed to create a temporary file path.

```
func retrieveProPic(proPicString: String, userID: String){
   let downloadedFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingString("downloaded-myImage.jpg")
   let downloadedFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: downloadedFilePath)

   let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
   downloadRequest.bucket = "profilepicturetest1"
   downloadRequest.key = userID
   downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadedFileURL

let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject? in
    if let error = task.error {
        print("Failed to download because of (\(error))")
    }
    if task.result != nil {

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: downloadedFileURL)

        {
            self.proPicImage = UIImage(data: data)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        print("made it to have result")

    } else {

        print ("Unexpected empty result")

    }

    return nil

}
```